# Java 8 grouping by first String attribute with different separators

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

From an object and through Java 8 stream/collector functionality, I want to create a String made of 2 different separators. "/" to separate the options of the same category, and  to separate the different categories.

**Expected output result :**

```
AJOUT option1 test / AJOUT option3 test </br> 
SUPPRESSION option2 test </br>
MODIFICATION option4 test / MODIFICATION option5 test
```

*Notes :*

- The uppercase words (AJOUT, SUPPRESSION, MODIFICATION) are the categories and are retrieved with method `option.getAction().getLabel()`
- The rest of the words stands for the option (ex: "option1 test" is an option name) and are retrieved through method `option.getLabel()`

**Here is my try:**

1- Separate all options with "/"

```
String description = orderCapture.getSelectedOptions().stream()
                    .map(option -> String.format("%s %s", option.getAction().getLabel(), option.getLabel()))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" / "));
```

*Result*

```
AJOUT option1 test / SUPPRESSION option2 test / AJOUT option3 test / MODIFICATION option4 test / MODIFICATION option5 test
```

2- Separate all options with "`&lt;br/&gt`" (`</br>`)

```
String description = orderCapture.getSelectedOptions().stream()
                    .map(option -> String.format("%s %s", option.getAction().getLabel(), option.getLabel()))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" &lt;br/&gt "));
```

*Result*

```
AJOUT option1 test </br> SUPPRESSION option2 test </br> AJOUT option3 test </br> MODIFICATION option4 test </br> MODIFICATION option5 test
```

3- My last try is to separate categories with the br tag but it is not working

```
String description = orderCapture.getSelectedOptions().stream()
                    .map(option -> String.format("%s %s", option.getAction().getLabel(), option.getLabel()))
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(option -> option.getAction().getLabel()), 
                             Collectors.joining(" &lt;br/&gt "));
```

*Result*

Eclipse error:

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Collector>> to Supplier
- The method collect(Supplier, BiConsumer, BiConsumer) in the type Stream is not applicable for the arguments 
   (Collector>>, Collector)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Related to the last of your attempt, you have `map`ped the option to `String` prior to trying to `group`. Further, as the message reads clearly, there isn't an overload that accepts two `Collectors` while using `collect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might have noticed the first of your implementation is useful to iterate over the list of `Option` if they are grouped properly. So using that as a utility method below --

```
private static String describeSimilarActions(List<Option> options) {
    return options.stream()
            .map(option -> String.format("%s %s", option.getAction().getLabel(), option.getLabel()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" / "));
}
```

and then grouping based on the `Action` label as expected to provide an appropriate line break can help as in:

```
String description = orderCapture.getSelectedOptions().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(op -> op.getAction().getLabel())) // this
        .values().stream()
        .map(opList -> describeSimilarActions(opList)) // reuse
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: Perfect solution. I use what I've already done, and I group it thanks to your clear suggestion. I just replace the separator with `&lt;br/&gt` because the carriage return should be seen on a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
Map<String, String> lines =
    orderCapture.getSelectedOptions()
                .stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(op -> op.getAction().getLabel(),
                                    mapping(op -> format("%s %s", op.getAction().getLabel(), op.getLabel()),
                                            joining(" / "))));

String description = lines.values()
                          .stream()
                          .collect(joining(" <br>\n"));
```

---

A little bit of explanation:

1. It streams over `selectedOptions`
2. Then it groups the options by `op.getAction().getLabel()`
3. Once grouped it maps each element of each group into a formatted string
4. Then it joins the elements of each group (formatted strings) into line strings
5. After all steps the data gets collected into a map with (`action label` -> `formatted line`) pairs

The second pipeline is pretty trivial. It just joins the values (formatted lines) from each key-value pair.

---

These two pipelines could be combined into a single chain, but I don't think it's any sort more readable. Adding it as an example here:

```
String description =
    orderCapture.getSelectedOptions()
                .stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(op -> op.getAction().getLabel(),
                                    mapping(op -> format("%s %s", op.getAction().getLabel(), op.getLabel()),
                                            joining(" / "))))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .collect(joining(" <br>\n"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried your suggestion but `groupingBy` and `mapping` were not found by my IDE. I searched for équivalents but didn't found. I think it is a smart idea to use a Map though.

Comment: @HéloïseChauvel they are static imports for `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.mapping`.